# How can I convert $14,500.00 from text to a number in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

As the title says: How can I convert data like `$14,500.00` and `$1,206.80` from text to a number in Google Sheets?

I tried the special format and then `$#,##0.00`but it didnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

`=iferror( value( regexreplace( trim(A2), "[^\d.]", "" ) & " " ) )`

The values you quote should be perfectly valid as is, provided that the spreadsheet locale is set to United States or another locale that uses period as decimal mark and $ as currency symbol. To avoid the need to convert these values in the first place, set **File > Settings > Locale** before you import the values.